# iOS - Image border or another image as border - performance wise which is better?

Tags: ios, performance, uiimageview, uiimage

I am new to iOS development. I am working in an app which has lots of images (table with each cell having an image). I need to show border for each image. Currently this is how I do it -

```
[image.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor red] CGColor]];
[image.layer setBorderWidth:2.5f];
```

This border width and colour is fixed for each image in the cell. Will it better if I instead use an image for border (in Xcode IB) instead of setting it every time at runtime?

Comment: Better to use what you're currently using.

Comment: You can make screenshot for every image before and save they in cashe.

Comment: This one is much easier, don't worry too much about performance issue before you really face one. Most of the time the worry was just a waste of time.